# bitcoinjs-lib node js raw transaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, bitcoinjs-lib

```js
var bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
var rp = require('request-promise');

var data = Buffer.from('Hello World', 'utf8');
var testnet = bitcoin.networks.testnet;
var privateKey = 'p2pkh';
var SourceAddress = "myaddress";

var url = "https://chain.so/api/v2/get_tx_unspent/BTCTEST/"+SourceAddress;
var DestionationAddress = '2MsHsi4CHXsaNZSq5krnrpP4WShNgtuRa9U';
var options = 
{
    uri: url,
    json: true
};

rp(options).then(function (response) {
    var index = response.data.txs.length - 1;
    console.log(response.data.txs[index]);
    var UtxoId = response.data.txs[index].txid;
    var vout = response.data.txs[index].output_no;
    var amount = Number(response.data.txs[index].value*100000000);
    var fee = 0.0005*100000000;
}).catch(function (err) { console.error(err);});

const RawTransaction = new bitcoin.TransactionBuilder(testnet);
RawTransaction.addInput(UtxoId, vout);
RawTransaction.addOutput(DestionationAddress, parseInt(amount-fee));
scrypt = bitcoin.script.compile([bitcoin.opcodes.OP_RETURN,data]);
RawTransaction.addOutput(scrypt, 0);

var keyPair = bitcoin.ECPair.fromWIF(privateKeyWIF, testnet);
tx.sign(0, keyPair);

const p2wpkh = bitcoin.payments.p2wpkh({ 
    pubkey: keyPair.publicKey, 
    network: bitcoin.networks.testnet 
});
const p2sh = bitcoin.payments.p2sh({ 
    redeem: p2wpkh, 
    network: bitcoin.networks.testnet
});
RawTransaction.sign(0, keyPair, p2sh.redeem.output, null, parseInt(amount));

var Transaction=RawTransaction.build().toHex();
var Sendingoptions = { method: 'POST', url: 'https://chain.so/api/v2/send_tx/BTCTEST',
body: {tx_hex: Transaction}, json: true};

rp(Sendingoptions).then(function (response) {
    var Jresponse = JSON.stringify(response);
    console.log("Transaction ID:\n"+Jresponse);

}).catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
```

I was trying to create a raw transaction but don't know why it's showing an error that UtoxId is not defined.

```
RawTransaction.addInput(UtxoId, vout);
                        ^

ReferenceError: UtxoId is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/Documents/blockchain/hello.js:27:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

I think this may contain more errors as it stopped at UtoxId. But I want to know how to resolve this and give my output as transaction id, script hex, value, time, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable UtxoId is part of the request-promise block.

Try:

```
let UtxoId
rp(options).then(function (response) {
    var index = response.data.txs.length - 1;
    console.log(response.data.txs[index]);
    UtxoId = response.data.txs[index].txid;
    var vout = response.data.txs[index].output_no;
    var amount = Number(response.data.txs[index].value*100000000);
    var fee = 0.0005*100000000;
}).catch(function (err) { console.error(err);});

const RawTransaction = new bitcoin.TransactionBuilder(testnet);
RawTransaction.addInput(UtxoId, vout);
```